# how to get a portion of a view outside of its parent?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried to create an actionBar like this one, "this is a website template "

[image]

so I created a file `action_bar.xml` which I'll inflate, A `RelativeLayout` which has a height of `wrap_content` & a width of `match_parent` , it has the gear icon and all other details except that I can't get a part of the round picture outside of the `RelativeLayout` like the picture.

I tried using margins but it doesn't get out of the `RelativeLayout`, The `RelativeLayout` gets extended instead. so, More `margin` in the picture results in more height in `RelativeLayout`. 
Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/roundPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
        android:padding="0sp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gearIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gearICON"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

No Libraries please, I'm not making an app, I'm just trying to understand.

quick recap. I want a part of the first `ImageButton` outside of the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#behavior Use this appbar and change the position as per your needs.

Comment: please provide the XML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I ran into a problem that my data appears under the ImageView, not behind it
but I fixed it by adding my data which is a listview, after the relativeLayout in the frameLayout, Thanks P.Juni for the idea btw
The XML which runs totally fine is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gearIcon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </ListView>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
        android:padding="0sp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is this what you are looking for

**EDIT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gearIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
    android:padding="0sp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This worked but, I really think this would miss things up. See the area between the end of the relativeLayout & the end of the frameLayout, will this area be empty? or will my contents show there?

Comment: it will be empty as it is the FrameLayout borders

Comment: Yep that's why I said it will miss things up

Comment: don't know what your desired goal is but you can play with backgrounds. See the edit.